# Using eval in the middle of a python statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use eval in the middle of the following python statement:

```
["a", "b"] + eval('[1,2].append(3)')
```

but because it does not return any value (it works in an "in place" manner), I cannot actually use it there and instead I receive an error of `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list` . Is there any way that I can fix this issue by getting return value out of eval in Python?

Comment: It's not that `eval` doesn't return anything here. It's that `list.append()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Axe319, you are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list concatenation instead of calling `append()`. It returns the new list.

```
["a", "b"] + eval('[1,2] + [3]')
```